# Можно ли узнать все айпи адреса хоста, зная лишь один из его айпи адресов?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сеть, tcp, dns

Можно ли узнать все айпи адреса хоста, зная лишь один из его айпи адресов?

Я имею в виду можно ли эту информацию получить без доступа к хосту. Например, через dns запросы или icmp запросы.

Если это важно, то на хосте установлена Debian 9, хост находится на ovh.

Comment: Нельзя. Никто не гарантирует, что в dns будут именно все адреса

Comment: а давайте попробуем решить обратную задачу: есть два ip-адреса, в них резолвятся два разных доменных имени. можно ли гарантированно установить, что при обращении по этим ip-адресам отвечает одно и то же сетевое устройство? если речь об одном широковещательном сегменте ethernet (т.е., в этом сегменте находится и тестирующее, и тестируемое устройство/устройства), то можно. иначе — нет.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin а как это проверить, что два адреса ведут на одно устройство? я использую ovh, кто угодно может получить диапазоны адресов ovh и проверить каждый адрес с известным адресом хоста. таким образом вычислить все адреса

Comment: ovh — это провайдер, кажется? он что, настолько мелкий, что у него только один датацентр, и в этом датацентре все компьютеры включены в единственный ethernet-коммутатор? если так и есть, то по ответам на arp-запросы можно определить, за одним ли ethernet-устройством закреплены такие-то ip-адреса, или за разыми. впрочем, никто ж не мешает к одному копьютеру подключить несколько ethernet-адаптеров, верно?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin я не знаю, как там все подключено. насколько я понял, ты имеешь в виду, что у адресов определяется общий mac адрес. а можно ли сделать так, чтобы разные адреса одного хоста имели разные mac адреса?

Comment: да, даже при наличии всего одного [ethernet-адаптера](https://serverfault.com/q/223601/292034). а если их больше одного… // `я не знаю, как там все подключено` — ну это был сарказм: про один датацентр и единственный ehternet-коммутатор на все серверы провайдера.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, даже, если единственный маршрутизатор, при правильно построенной сети вы не увидите «чужие» пакеты, а значит и ответа на вопрос не получите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментах ответили, что нельзя.